# Trying to process a file output via awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to parse output of the following command

```
hdfs dfs -count
```

For the most part I can get what I want, however, I am having issue with the first piece

```
   1           23            1118275 /user/data/system/sys_1/...
   1           23            1515762 /user/data/system/sys_2/...
   1           23            1892459 /user/data/system/sys_3/...
```

I am using awk to process...e.g.,...

```
 awk ' BEGIN { FS="[/]"; OFS="," } { print $1,$2,$3,$(NF-1),$0 } '
```

...but I get the first block as unprocessed, e.g.,...

```
   1           23            1118275 
   1           23            1515762 
   1           23            1892459
```

I have tried...

```
{ FS="[ /]"; OFS="," }
```

but with a space but that gives me an output of commmas, it doesn't see the /

So, summary, I can parse via / but only to a point, it seems to ignore the block spaces.

If there is confusion on this I apologize, it quite tricky to explain what is going on. Basically the $1 is a block and I can't process it correctly. I tried to parse it as part of the FS=" /" but that doesn't work at all.

substr($1,x,y) doesn't work properly either, it sees to be treating the block as something that can't be split. I am doing this now...

```
awk ' BEGIN { FS="[/]" } { print substr($1,37) } '
```

and I isolate the file size...

```
 1118275
 1515762
 1892459
 1990075
  882355
 2125763
 1841735
 2260994
 1082926
13649144
```

But if I try something like this...

```
 awk ' BEGIN { FS="[/]" } { print substr($1,24,24) } '
```

I get this...

```
23            1118275
23            1515762
23            1892459
23            1990075
23             882355
23            2125763
23            1841735
```

I hope this is a bit clearer, but it may not be.

Comment: What is it that the command outputs? What are your desired results? It's not clear and I don't have a Hadoop box to run the command to see what it spits out.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but it sounds like you want to do additional processing on the contents of the first field for each record.  Have you thought about omitting the OFS parameter entirely, and then manipulating the contents of $1 before doing the print command for each line?

Comment: the command would be like hdfs dfs -count /user/data/system/*...it spits out the directory, partitions and file sizes associated with each record...the count is like doing an hdfs dfs -ls except instead of the files listed I get a summary of the files under the directory...I am looking to have an output of 1,23,1118275, i.e., comma separated...at the moment all I get is 1           23            1118275 which is not comma separated even though I tried to specify as a FS=" /"...at least with FS="/" I get an output that is semi-usable...when I try to FS on " " I get a blank output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quick-and-dirty response, but based on your comment, is this close to what you want?

```
BEGIN { FS="[/]"; OFS="," } {
    z = split($1,aa," ")
    print aa[1],aa[2],aa[3],$2,$3,$(NF-1),$0
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I did this awk ' BEGIN { FS="[/]"; OFS=","  } { split($1,a," "); print a[2],a[3] } ' and managed to split the $1 block and got this out 23,1118275, etc.